# How to run multiple threads concurrently in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have created a jmeter script which has 4 threads

```
Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 3
Thread 4
```

Here every subsequent thread uses the response from the previous thread. Now say suppose in the Test Plan section I select 'Run Thread Groups consecutively (i.e. one at a time) and for each of these requests I set 'Number of Threads' = 100, so I wanted to understand how the execution is done ? When the script is run and Thread 1 is getting executed are all 100 threads of Thread 1 executed concurrently ?
Now I want to run another case in which all the 4 threads are executed in parallel i.e. in my example above 100 requests from each of threads which means that 400 threads are executed in parallel. This is the requirement but the limitation here is that all 4 threads cannot be executed in parallel as I said earlier that each thread depends on the response from the previous thread.
So I want to run this script in such a way that say at some point in time Thread 1 is getting executed concurrently Thread 4 is getting executed (but note that for the requests in Thread 4, Thread 1 was already executed).
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What `threads`? In JMeter there are [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) which run threads (virtual users)

If there is a dependency on the previous response be informed that [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are local to the thread even if they are in the same Thread Group.

If you need to pass the values between thread groups - most probably something is wrong with your test design and you should move your [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) to one Thread Group

If the following are your strict requirements:

- 400 parallel users in 4 different Thread Groups
- Ability to pass data between Thread Groups

you can take a look at [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)